# My Dataflow job is taking over an hour to start

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

My job submitted to Dataflow is taking over an hour to start.

The region is set to `europe-west1`.

I set my `flexrs_goal` to `SPEED_OPTIMIZED`.

The dependencies are:

```
import gzip
import json
import logging
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import WriteToBigQuery
from apache_beam.io.gcp import bigquery
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.types import Query
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.datastoreio import (
    ReadFromDatastore,
)
```

What could be the reason for such a long delay? Is it:

1. GCP resource provisioning delays (that are GCPs fault)
2. Issues with my code (additional dependencies that take a long time to install submitted?)
3. Configuration of FlexRs

Comment: What are your parameter? Machine Types? Your quotas?

Comment: Do you use https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers?

Comment: It is very unusual. Do you see any logs during that startup time that would indicate what it is doing?